# How to view apk icons in Nautilus?

Tags: icons, thumbnails

I want to view .apk (android apps) on Nautilus. There's already a solution for Windows e.g. apkshellext but it's not supported for Linux or Ubuntu. So, how can I view apk icon in thumbnail on Ubuntu?

Comment: There's currently no APK thumbnailer in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the same thing, I haven't found anything.

So I've done a simple APK thumbnailer script and published the setup procedure at http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/76-gnome/284-gnome-shell-generate-apk-thumbnail-nautilus

Hope it helps.